# Changing arrow head in tikz using circuit ee IEC current direction

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, circuits

I am indicating the current direction in my circuit by using `\node[current direction={}]`. In the code below, you can see that the arrow head under the label `i_L` is different from the arrow head of the voltage `u_L`. I tried to change the arrow head of the current direction to the style "latex" by defining by own arrow `IPfeil`. Unfortunately, I didn't work. I have also tried it with `\tikzet{>=latex}`, but this didn't work either.

Does anyone know how to change the arrow head?

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
% Define arrows
\tikzset{
     Pfeil/.style={thin,shorten >=#1,shorten <=#1,->,>=latex},
     UPfeil/.style={blue,Pfeil=#1,font={\sffamily\itshape\footnotesize}},
     IPfeil/.style={red,Pfeil=#1,font={\sffamily\itshape\footnotesize}},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
    \draw[semithick] ([xshift=6cm]90:1 and 1.25) |- (8,4);
    \draw[semithick] ([xshift=6cm]60:1.75 and 2) ++(0.5, 0) |- (8,3);
    \draw[fill=white] (8,4) circle (1.5pt);     
    \draw[fill=white] (8,3) circle (1.5pt);
    % Voltage arrow             
    \draw[UPfeil=0.4em] ([xshift=0em]8,4) -- node[right]{\(u_{L}\)} ([xshift=0em]8,3);
    % Current arrow
    \tikzset{current direction arrow/.style={IPfeil=0em}},
    \node[current direction={red, rotate=180, info'={[IPfeil=0em,red, above]\(i_L\)}}] at (7.5,4) {};       
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the correct arrow tip is `direction ee`.  Section 47.4.8 “Implementation: The EE-Symbols Shape Library” of the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) knows more:

> [image]

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
% Define arrows
\tikzset{
     Pfeil/.style={thin,shorten >=#1,shorten <=#1,->,>=direction ee},
     UPfeil/.style={blue,Pfeil=#1,font={\sffamily\itshape\footnotesize}},
     IPfeil/.style={red,Pfeil=#1,font={\sffamily\itshape\footnotesize}},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
    \draw[semithick] ([xshift=6cm]90:1 and 1.25) |- (8,4);
    \draw[semithick] ([xshift=6cm]60:1.75 and 2) ++(0.5, 0) |- (8,3);
    \draw[fill=white] (8,4) circle (1.5pt);     
    \draw[fill=white] (8,3) circle (1.5pt);
    % Voltage arrow             
    \draw[UPfeil=0.4em] ([xshift=0em]8,4) -- node[right]{\(u_{L}\)} ([xshift=0em]8,3);
    % Current arrow
    \tikzset{current direction arrow/.style={IPfeil=0em}},
    \node[current direction={red, rotate=180, info'={[IPfeil=0em,red, above]\(i_L\)}}] at (7.5,4) {};       
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. The page in the manual was very helpful. I can change the arrow head of the current arrow with this command: \node[current direction={thick, red, direction ee arrow = latex, rotate=180, info'={[IPfeil=0em, red, above](i_L)}}] at (7.5,4) {};